# WordPress Permalink won't save (.htaccess, httpd.conf correct)

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

WP install won't update the Permalinks from the 'edit' page. Clicking 'Ok' appears to save the state, but updating the post never publishes the post-name change.

Having reviewed the docs, http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks :

- .htaccess has standard WP rewrite rules.
- httpd.conf AllowOverride is All
- Plug-ins are disabled
- Using standard format:

  - Post name - http://livingston-new.dev/sample-post/

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes post slugs you've used in the past can become 'reserved' if they were sent to the trash but not actually deleted.

Take a look in your trash area and delete any posts you don't need, this usually fixes the problem of permalinks not being saved on a post level.

Comment: In this case, this is not likely the problem. I am changing from English to French, so I know that there is no chance for post names to exist already. Thank you for this insight though, it might be useful in tracking down the issue yet.